# How do I include records lacking one half of a join?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    s.staffID as staffID, 
    CONCAT_WS(", ", lname, fname) AS name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(unit SEPARATOR ", ") AS units 
FROM 
    staff s, 
    units u, 
    staff_units r 
WHERE 
    s.staffID = r.staffID 
    AND u.unitID = r.unitID 
GROUP BY s.staffID 
ORDER BY lname
```

This gets a list something like this:

```
Alice    Accounting
Bob      Systems
Charlie  Customer Services, Administration
```

Okay so far.  Now suppose that I delete the entry in `staff_units` that records Alice as a member of Accounting.  Running this query will then yield a list from which Alice is excluded even though she still exists in the `staff` table:

```
Bob      Systems
Charlie  Customer Services, Administration
```

Can I adjust this SQL so that it continues to return Alice as a result, showing her as unassigned to a unit?

I could of course run one query to get a list of staff, and another query for each one of them to get current assignments.  But that would mean running n+1 queries to build the list, where n is the number of staff, and that just rubs me wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use a [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Applied to your statement, this would become

```
SELECT 
    s.staffID as staffID, 
    CONCAT_WS(", ", lname, fname) AS name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(unit SEPARATOR ", ") AS units 
FROM 
    staff s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_units r ON s.staffID = r.staffID     
    LEFT OUTER JOIN units u ON u.unitID = r.unitID 
GROUP BY s.staffID 
ORDER BY lname
```

Note that the [implicit type of join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins) you are using is becoming deprecated.

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick.  Thanks.  I'll accept in a few minutes once the cooldown expires.

Comment: @WillMartin - Thank you but do take the note serious. Once you learn to use the explicit join syntax, you will find it much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks, I'll invest some time in that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

So your query will be

```
SELECT 
    s.staffID as staffID, 
    CONCAT_WS(", ", lname, fname) AS name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(unit SEPARATOR ", ") AS units 
FROM 
    {staff s LEFT OUTER JOIN  staff_units r ON s.staffID=r.staffID}
```